# Put if on the value of the Features product.tpl (prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-themes

I have a feature called badge and its value is Customized value.
Now the value is once Luxery, once Our Advice or maybe both (Our Advice, Luxery)

Now how should I change this code so that the conditions are correct for everyone

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
 {if $feature.id_feature == 8 && $feature.value == 'Our Advice, Luxery'}
   <div>test for both</div>
 {elseif $feature.id_feature == 8 && $feature.value == 'Luxery'}
   <div>test for Luxery</div>
 {elseif $feature.id_feature == 8 && $feature.value == 'Our Advice'}
   <div>test for Our Advice</div>
 {/if}
{/foreach}
```

**Note: I use several languages**

Thanks for the help